# Casting 0-1 int r-value to bool

Tags: c++, performance

I have an expression which returns 0 or 1 integer as a temporary value. The value is probably already in a register and I would like to return it as a bool from an inlined function.

Is there an ordinary way to do this? I believe `(bool)` and `static_cast<bool>` inject additional test and set instructions. And this is too much for me, while the case is about a performance critical part of memory manager.

Comment: Have you actually checked that the cast does add extra instructions? It may be that the compiler can optimise this away.

Comment: So what exactly is your memory manager doing that you need to worry about the performance of casting `int` to `bool`? I ask because I wonder how you can manage memory so cheaply that this is your bottleneck (you have profiled it, haven't you?).

Comment: @Grizzly, it indeed perform cheaply, as it works with preallocate blocks. -- Only on blocks (de)allocation and data removals (if data objects are big) it slows down.

Comment: @Number47: So how much do those implicit casts actually hurt you? Because if it is enough to matter I would assume that you want to make sure the code is inlined anyways, since the cost of a function call would hurt to.

Comment: @Grizzly Perhaps the test is in a tight loop within the allocator.  (One common trick I've seen used to reduce the overhead of the allocator is to put the flag allocated or free on the least significant bit of a pointer, given that alignment constraints mean that the actual address must be even.)

Comment: @Ben, I hoped for something, which will not depend on a compiler's caprice.

Comment: @Number47 The only thing that doesn't depend on what the compiler does is assembler.  Any thing you write in C++ is at the mercy of the compiler.  Always.  But of course, the compiler authors aren't intentionally out to give you bad performance.

Comment: @James, I was little to eager in words. I just wanted to give the compiler a hint that this value is indeed bool. I can believe, with such hint it will optimize properly, but without it, it is little like depending on magic.

Comment: @Number47 Compilers are magic:-).  They're actually pretty good at optimizations like these.

Comment: @James, still I get `'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)` warning, which doesn't look so optimistic. I know it can just be cased by that the compiler is not aware of optimization at the point of processing the function. But I can really barely trust the magic seeing such messages.

Comment: @Number47 Well, it's all very compiler dependent.  When you mentioned elsewhere `-O3`, I assumed g++, but the message you quote above suggests VC++ (to me, at least).  And of course, a lot depends on the expression generating `0` or `1`.

Comment: @James, it needs to work both with vc and gcc. And yes, it is very compiler dependent. That is why I wanted to ensure as much as possible to the compiler do what it should do. The expression is exactly `uc >> 7`, where uc is unsigned char field in a struct. -- But I actually am not even sure, why it complains about, it is an int not an unsigned char, or at least an unsigned int. ... And how I can trust compilers? :/

Answer (score 7):

Just return it. *Any* value, different from `0` is `true` and `0` is `false` in c++.

Just `return` the `int` from your inline function (which returns `bool`).

Comment: It should be, but at least without inlining, it will involve implicit cast and additional instructions, which I don't want to.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your integer expression is `foo`, then use `!!foo` to get the `bool` value.

Comment: Or simply `foo` (if that suffices - which is true for many cases).

Comment: @Nawaz Sure that will do in most cases. Just in case OP really need a value of type `bool` exactly.

Comment: This involves additional CPU instructions, which I marked I don't want to.

Comment: @Number47 Then return them directly if that suits you.

Comment: No. It involves an implicit conversion, which inserts additional instructions.

Comment: That's horrible advice.  He should be writing `foo != 0`.  Of course, a lot depends on what he's doing with the resulting value, but there is never a situation where `!!foo` is anything but obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing with the return value?  If you are using it
immediately in condition, the compiler will probably generate
exactly the same code, regardless of whether the type is `bool`
or not.  There will be a simple comparison with `0`.  If you are
assigning it to a `bool` variable, the compiler will generally
generate an extra instruction, to ensure that the binary value
is either `0` or `1` (and not some other value).  But what is
the expression, so that you can be sure that it is either 0 or
1?  If it is something like `x & 1`, a good compiler will
recognize this, and will optimize out the extra instruction.

EDIT:

I might add that I am assuming inlining and optimization.
If performance is an issue, those are the first two steps
you should take.

Comment: About the edit: I am not sure, about would it be safe to use -O3 as I already use assembler in the code. Isn't it a threat for eager optimization?

Comment: @Number47 It depends on the compiler, but in general, inline assembler shouldn't be a problem: g++ has a means of annotating the assembler, so that the compiler knows pretty much everything it needs to know about it, and other compilers will generally assume the worst (or document what you can and cannot do).  On the other hand, memory management often involves some tricky aliasing, which can confuse optimizers.  g++ has very detailed options for controlling optimizations, which you should study carefully, but off hand `-O3 -fnostring-aliasing` might be the appropriate combination.

Answer (score 1):

When I come across such performance warnings in cppcheck, I usually use the most elegant approach for this (at least in my opinion ;) ):

`return yourInt != 0;`

This sticks with the assumption that all values different from 0 are considered true.

Comment: This is, at least, the most readable, supposing the function returns `int`.  Without optimization and inlining, it will require one or two extra instructions compared to returning `int`.  But of course, if performance is an issue, he will be using optimization and inlining, so he might as well do it correctly.

Comment: Hopefully no one is ever "optimizing" functions/methods like this^^

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
return rtVal;
```

just return the integer will return true if it isn't 0

Answer (score 0):

from c++ 2012 standard (ISO/IEC N3337):

> 4.12 Boolean conversions
>
> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
> prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
> any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of
> type bool; the resulting value is false.

So just return it?!

Comment: But it involves conversion, so it will inject additional instructions. When the proper bool value -- which is 0 or 1 -- is already in a register.

Comment: @Number47 But who do you expect, how to convert a value without converting it?

Comment: I know the value is a proper bool value and want to force the compiler to treat it as a bool value without implicit casting. I want something like `reinterpret_cast<bool>(my_int_expression)`. But this actually is forbidden.

Comment: so declare it internal as bool?

Comment: @Number47 if you cant so, you cant force the compiler to treat it as true bool, because it wont be on runtime the whole time bool, so there has to be a sidestep of conversion. --- So: If you can use ti the whole time jsut as bool, then alse declare it as a bool type, if you cant, because you do arithmetic operations on it tehn teh compiler needs to treat it as integer type for math. So both cases are prety simple. On the one hand just make return type boool. Or you have to accept the conversion.

Comment: This is like `int_value >> 31`. So rather can't declare it as bool from the beginning. But surly it a bool value fulfilling the standard, even if it would need to be cut to the lowest byte. So there is no point in doing implicit not identity conversion. If I can say the compiler that, a pointer is of a different type then it is, and it will not involve any non-trivial conversion, then why I can't make it here?

Comment: @Number47 `int_value >> 31` is an operation that is only allowed on integer types, so it has to be an integer, and so it has to be casted. As simply as this. It is same, as Would I ask "I'm now a woman, and i were a man, how can I make to never have been a man?" you need it to be an integer to do this operation and you cant make a conversion from integer to bool without doing a conversion, thats the simple point, I don't know how to say it more clear.

Comment: @Number47 With saying that a pointer is of a different type you mean a `reinterpret_cast` of the pointer? Well you can do it (as in the compiler lets you). However dereferencing the resulting pointer is forbidden by the language, so the situation isn't that different.

Comment: @Number47 If in `int_value >> 31`, `int_value` is an `int`, the results will not be `0` or `1` on most machines, but `0` and `-1` (but they're very implementation defined, of course).  If `int_value` is an unsigned 32 bit integral type, on the other hand, they will be `0` or `1`, and g++, at least, recognizes this, and doesn't generate the extra instruction to ensure it.

Comment: @James Kanze thats what I'm the whole time saying v.v

Comment: @Zaibis, you are only saying you don't understand, how things are going under the abstraction layer of the language.

Comment: @Number47 even if, then you shouldn't tag your question as c++ if you don't want a answer based on c++ knowledge, but know it. Probably you jsut don't understand the point why it is pardoxial what you are asking for.

Comment: @Zaibis, I am not sure is the best taste to say this to a computer scientist specialized in programing languages theory? Actually C++ is a quite low level language and it is common to use many not too clean tricks with it. bool is actually a value set, which in most implementations is {0, 1} laid on 1, 2, 4 (8?) bytes. And from technical point of view there is no sense to non-trivial cast to bool an int which we can guarantee, it is 0 or 1. -- And yes, C++ is an unclean language from the very beginning and if you are not aware of it, it is a bad idea to use it.